# Two service in one application, the second does not want start

Tags: c#, windows, service

I have in one application two services. The second one does not want start;

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
    ControlService controlService = ControlService.Instance;
    CommService commService = CommService.Instance;
    ServiceBase[] servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[]{controlService, commService };
    ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
}
```

I changed the order of the services, and always the second service is not starting

Comment: Are you trying to start one service, when the previous one has not yet finished and you are not doing Multitasking/Multithreading?

Comment: Is the `OnStart` method called in both services?

Comment: OnStart is called only on first one. I put breakpoints on both

Comment: There is a post on MSDN with the same problem (and an answer) https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a062b1e8-7425-4ba9-b038-a5973fd2150d/i-cant-start-2-windows-services-in-one-process-please-help?forum=csharpgeneral